# Solidify problem with borders 2.79

Tags: modifiers

I take a circle, extrude it, and solidify and obtain a kind of cylinder.
If I deform the cylinder, the border becomes skewed.

How can I have a flat border as if the cylinder was cut with a knife?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this easily in Blender 2.82+.

In the *Solidify Modifier*

- Set *Mode* to *Complex*.
- Set *Boundary* to *Flat*.

[image]

Comment: Cool, but im stil with 2,79 :(

Comment: well thank yo very much for your answer and your time :-)

Comment: because i have to upgrade the macos first, i have to make backup then, change software.. well you know