# How to make a cylinder / pipe with slanted ends (like pasta penne)?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am trying to recreate a penne pasta. I am creating a cylinder removing the two end faces and then I solidify the mesh.

However I do not know how to extrude (or cut away) the two ends to make them pointy like in the picture of the penne below. I have tried to use bisect and mirror, but without successful results.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Heh, I saw the title in the Hot Network Question and thought I'd end up on the [cooking.se] site ...

Comment: @Glorfindel same here haha, and I was honestly hoping to find out how it's done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In edit mode select all the vertices and use the shear tool (shift+control+alt+S)

[image]

Comment: When you add the solidify modifier it creates a lip that extends outside of the cylinder in the length, how to prevent that?

Comment: @Luciano Since Blender 2.82 it's no longer a problem: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167603/

Answer (score 5):

Lets make this using only one vertex and a bunch of modifiers.
Recommended version : 2.83.

Displace the vertex, add a screw modifier to get a circle, add another screw modifier to get a cylinder.

[image]

Add a bend deform modifier to shear the cylinder, an empty object with an array to mirror along Z and X, and a solidify for the thickness.

[image]

Tweak it !

[image]

Thanks to [Jachym Michal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167603/86891) for pointing out the complex method in the solidify modifier.